# ROBLOX: attempt to index nil with 'TweenSize'

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

I try to making roading bar
but error "attempt to index nil with 'TweenSize'"
how can I fix it?

```
local gui = script.Parent
local background = gui:WaitForChild("Background")
local bar = background:WaitForChild("Bar")
local filler = bar:WaitForChild("Filler",5)
local percentage = bar:WaitForChild("Percent")

for i = 1, 100 do
    wait(0.04)
    percentage.Text = i.."%"

    local formula = i/100

    filler:TweenSize(UDim2.new(formula, 0, 1, 0), Enum.EasingDirection.InOut, Enum.EasingStyle.Quart, 0.5, true)
end
```

Comment: Well, `filler` is nil. Make sure its not nil. For example by removing the timeout which allows it to be nil.

Comment: I'd like to say that this code will not work properly even after applying the fix @Luke100000 said. It'll look like it works (somewhat), but in reality, you're wasting a lot of resources. You're trying to use a for loop based smooth changing system. If you want to tween the size in half a second, get just get rid of the for loop, and make it so `formula` is initialized to `1`. Then, cut the part starting with `wait` and ending with `"%"`, and paste that after the tween in a for loop with a `0.01` second wait.